# Getting grey screen when navigating from one screen to another in android. Everything working fine in IOS

Tags: android, react-native

Getting following error when navigating from one screen to another.

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in F
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in k
    in Unknown
    in PanGestureHandler
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in k
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in T
    in Unknown
    in RNSScreen
    in k
    in Unknown
    in o
    in Suspense
    in Unknown
    in q
    in l
    in s
    in Unknown
    in RNSScreenContainer
    in ScreenContainer
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in R
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider
    in Unknown
    in p
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView
    in Unknown
    in S
    in Unknown
    in u
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in y, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1107:14081
F@1107:13345
Cr@48:43504
Rl@48:55175
Sa@48:96772
vi@48:86899
gi@48:86801
hi@48:86566
oi@48:83486
pt@48:27332
Za@48:79770
al@48:49088
anonymous@562:465
anonymous@598:1424
anonymous@610:748
t@609:296
O@606:521
anonymous@606:750
j@606:575
anonymous@606:730
anonymous@800:9550
tryCallOne@53:15
anonymous@139:26
anonymous@79:1661
k@79:497
w@79:887
callReactNativeMicrotasks@79:3054
value@33:2867
anonymous@33:959
value@33:2503
value@33:918
value@33:853
```

Above error is showing in android studio while running debug apk on physical device.

My main problem is i am not able to understand where is the error.

Below is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, StatusBar, SafeAreaView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, TextInput, Animated, ScrollView, FlatList, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, Avatar, CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Polygon, Marker, LatLng, mapStyle, Polyline, enableLatestRenderer } from 'react-native-maps';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';

import axios from 'axios';
const API_KEY = 'Key';

enableLatestRenderer();

const PlanewTripmain = ({ navigation: { goBack } }) => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const [start_latlng, setstart_latlng] = useState('');
    const [end_latlng, setend_latlng] = useState('');
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
    const [selected, SetSelected] = useState(false)
    const [LoginData, setLoginData] = useState([]);
    const [TripData, setTripData] = useState(null)
    const [Markerer, setMarker] = useState([])
    const [locations, setlocations] = useState()
    const [Pharmacydetaillist, setPharmacydetaillist] = useState([])
    const ref = React.useRef();
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([]);
    const myTheme = {
        roundness: 4,
        colors: {
            primary: '#369B5F',
            accent: '#D9D9D9',
        },
    };
    const pharmacylist = []
    useEffect(() => {

        route.params.responseJson[0].data.map((item) => {
            // 
            const data = { "latitude": parseFloat(item.ph_LatLong.split(',')[0]), "longitude": parseFloat(item.ph_LatLong.split(',')[1]) }
            polygons.push(data);
            const datapList = { ...item, checked: false }
            pharmacylist.push(datapList)
        });

    })
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoginData(route.params.LoginData.data[0])
        setTripData(route.params.responseJson);
        setMarker(polygons);
        setPharmacydetaillist(pharmacylist)
    }, [])
    const MyStatusBar = ({ backgroundColor, ...props }) => (
        <View style={[styles.statusBar, { backgroundColor }]}>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={backgroundColor} {...props} />
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );

    const polygons = []

    const origin = {
        latitude: 41.878114,
        longitude: -87.6297778,
    };
    const destination = {
        latitude: 38.6268888,
        longitude: -90.1989143,
    }
    const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState({
        option1: false,
        option2: false,
        option3: false,
        option4: false
    });
    const handleCheckboxChange = (item) => {
        if (checkedItems.includes(item)) {
            setCheckedItems(checkedItems.filter((i) => i !== item));
        } else {
            setCheckedItems([...checkedItems, item]);
        }
    }

    const startTrip = async (actionType) => {
        console.log('Start Trip clicked')

        const npidata = checkedItems.map((item) => {
            return item.ph_NPI;
        })
        const bodyData = { "start_loc": route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].startAddress, "end_loc": route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].endAddress, "start_latlng": route.params.responseJson[1].start_latlng, "end_latlng": route.params.responseJson[1].end_latlng, "trip_name": route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].tripName, "ph_npi": npidata.join(), "trip_flag": actionType };
        fetch(`Api url`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(bodyData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${route.params.LoginData.data[0].token}`
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                GetstartTripdetail(responseJson[0].objectUid)
            })
            .catch((error) => {

                console.error(error);
            });

    };
    const GetstartTripdetail = async (objectUid) => {

        console.log('GetstartTripdetail clicked')

        const bodyDataa = { "objectUid": objectUid };
        fetch(`Api url`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(bodyDataa),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${route.params.LoginData.data[0].token}`
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                const points = responseJson[0].pharmacies.map((item) => {
                    return { latitude: parseFloat(item.ph_LatLong.split(',')[0]), "longitude": parseFloat(item.ph_LatLong.split(',')[1]) }
                })
               
                const origin = { latitude: responseJson[0].startLatLong.split(",")[0], longitude: responseJson[0].startLatLong.split(",")[1] };
                const destination = { latitude: responseJson[0].endLatLong.split(",")[0], longitude: responseJson[0].endLatLong.split(",")[1] };
                const waypoints = points;
                debugger;
                navigation.navigate('TripDetail', { responseJson, LoginData })
                openMapWithRoute(origin, destination, waypoints);

            })
            .catch((error) => {

                console.error(error);
            });

    };
    const openMapWithRoute = (origin, destination, waypoints) => {
        let waypointsString = '';
        waypoints.forEach((waypoint) => {
            waypointsString += `${waypoint.latitude},${waypoint.longitude}|`;
        });
        waypointsString = waypointsString.slice(0, -1);
        const url = `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}&destination=${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}&waypoints=${waypointsString}`;
        Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {

            if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(url);
            } else {
                console.log("Don't know how to open URI: " + url);
            }
        });
    };
    return (
        <View style={[styles.containerPlanned]}>
            <MyStatusBar backgroundColor="#2A524B" barStyle="light-content" />
            {/* <View style={styles.appBar} /> */}
            <View style={styles.headerarea}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => goBack()}>
                    <Image
                        source={require('./assets/images/back_white.png')}
                        style={styles.menuicon}
                    />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <Text style={styles.ongoingtriptxt}>Plan a New Trip</Text>
            </View>
            {route.params.responseJson != null &&
                <>
                    <View style={styles.MapArea}>
                        <MapView
                            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                            style={styles.map}
                            initialRegion={{
                                latitude: route.params.responseJson[0].polygonBoundries[5].latitude,
                                longitude: route.params.responseJson[0].polygonBoundries[5].longitude,
                                latitudeDelta: 1,
                                longitudeDelta: 2 * (screenWidth / 291),
                            }}

                        >
                            {/* {locations.map(marker => ( */}

                            <Polygon
                                coordinates={route.params.responseJson[0].polygonBoundries}
                                strokeColor="#f00"
                                fillColor="rgba(255,0,0,0.2)"
                                strokeWidth={1}
                                zIndex={9}
                            />

                            <MapViewDirections
                                origin={route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].startAddress}
                                destination={route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].endAddress}
                                apikey={API_KEY}
                                strokeWidth={1}
                                strokeColor="#111111"
                                mode="DRIVING"
                            />
                            {/* ))
                            } */}
                            {Markerer.map((markerr, index) => (
                                <Marker key={index}
                                    coordinate={markerr}
                                // style={{ width: 13, height: 20 }}
                                >
                                    <View>
                                        <Image source={require('./assets/images/location.png')}
                                            style={styles.markericon}></Image>
                                    </View>
                                </Marker>
                            ))}
                        </MapView>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.foundpharmacyparent}>
                        <View style={styles.tripnameparent_box}>
                            <Text style={styles.tripname}>{route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].tripName}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.editbtn}>Edit Details</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View >
                            <Text style={styles.triplocation}>{route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].startAddress} - {route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].endAddress}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.noofpharnamebox}>
                            <Text style={[styles.tripname, styles.size16]}>
                                {route.params.responseJson[0].tripdetails[0].pharmacyCount} Pharmacies found
                    </Text>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('./assets/images/filterbtn.png')}
                                    style={styles.filterbtn}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('./assets/images/sort_green.png')}
                                    style={styles.menubtn}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                        <SafeAreaView>
                            <ScrollView style={[styles.scrollView, checkedItems.length >= 1 ? styles.scrollViewchecked : ""]}>
                                {Pharmacydetaillist.map((item, index) => (
                                    <ListItem key={index + 'a'} style={styles.ListItem} containerStyle={{
                                        paddingLeft: 8,
                                        paddingRight: 0,
                                        alignItems: 'flex-start',
                                        backgroundColor: checkedItems.includes(item) ? '#EAF9F0' : 'white',
                                        paddingBottom: 0
                                    }}>
                                        <CheckBox
                                            value={checkedItems.includes(item)}
                                            onValueChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(item)}
                                            checked={checkedItems.includes(item)}
                                            // containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
                                            uncheckedIcon={<Image source={require('./assets/images/unchecked.png')} />}
                                            checkedIcon={<Image source={require('./assets/images/checked.png')} />}
                                            onPress={() => handleCheckboxChange(item)}
                                        />

                                        {item.logo &&
                                            <View style={styles.avatar}>
                                                <SvgUri
                                                    uri={item.logo}
                                                />
                                            </View>
                                        }
                                        {!item.logo &&
                                            <View style={styles.avatarr}>
                                                <Text style={styles.avatartxt}>{item.pharmacy_Name.split(" ")[0].at(0)}{item.pharmacy_Name.split(" ").slice(-1)[0].at(0)}</Text>

                                            </View>
                                        }
                                        <ListItem.Content style={styles.listitemcontent}>
                                            <View style={styles.Title_parent}>
                                                <Text style={styles.Title}>
                                                    {item.pharmacy_Name}
                                                </Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
                                                <Text style={styles.from_to_location}>{item.pharmacy_Address}</Text>
                                                <Text style={styles.no_of_visits}>{item.transactions} Transactions . {item.no_Of_Visits} Visits . {item.last_Visit_date}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <Text style={{ height: 1, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#E8E8E8", marginTop: 15 }}></Text>
                                        </ListItem.Content>
                                    </ListItem>
                                ))}
                            </ScrollView>
                        </SafeAreaView>

                    </View>
                    {checkedItems.length >= 1 &&
                        <View style={styles.SelectedParent}>
                            <Text style={styles.selecteditemsboxText}>
                                {checkedItems.length} Pharmacies Selected
                        </Text>
                            <View style={styles.selectedPharbtnParent}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Selectedsavebtn} onPress={() => { startTrip('Created') }
                                }>
                                    <Text style={styles.SelectedsavebtnText}>Save</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Selectedstarttripbtn} onPress={() => { startTrip('Started') }
                                }>
                                    <Text style={styles.SelectedstarttripText}>Start Trip</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    }
                </>
            }

        </View>

    );
};
const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = StatusBar.currentHeight;
const APPBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 : 56;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;


export default PlanewTripmain;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue after going through line by line into my code.
The issue was into this line

```
<Text style={styles.avatartxt}>{item.pharmacy_Name.split(" ")[0].at(0)}{item.pharmacy_Name.split(" ").slice(-1)[0].at(0)}</Text>
```

Seems like inline JS not supported in React Native Android.